# Change value in a list that is binded?

Tags: c#, list, combobox

I'm pretty new at this. Using Windows Forms in Visual Studio. I am to hammer out a store that has clothes, with stock that can be transferred in or out of the store. 
I've gotten as far as to having a class, a list that contains the clothes and their quantities, and I've managed to get them into comboboxes. What I want to do now is to be able to 'buy' new quantities, changing the value in the list.

I'm stumped as to how to change the actual quantities, I'm sure I am missing stuff here.

This is my class:

```
public class Store
{

    public string Clothing { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public Store(string c,  int q)
    {
        Clothing = c;

        Quantity = q;
    }
```

And this is my current code:

```
}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    List<Store> stock = new List<Store>

    {

    new Store ("Jeans size S", 1),
    new Store ("Jeans size M", 3),
    new Store ("Jeans size L", 5)

    };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void bShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cbStockType.ValueMember = "Clothing";
        cbStockType.DisplayMember = "Clothing";
        cbStockType.DataSource = stock;

        cbStockQnt.ValueMember = "Quantity";
        cbStockQnt.DisplayMember = "Quantity";
        cbStockQnt.DataSource = stock;

}

    private void lblHighlightAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void bSlctClothing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbStockType.SelectedIndex < 0)

        { lblHighlightAdd.Text = "None"; }

        else

        lblHighlightAdd.Text = cbStockType.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string quantityToAdd = tbQntAdd.Text;
        int add = Convert.ToInt32(quantityToAdd);

        string addToStock = cbStockQnt.SelectedValue.ToString();
        int newAmount = Convert.ToInt32(addToStock);
        int result = newAmount + add;

        foreach (var item in stock)
        {
            if (item.Clothing == cbStockType.SelectedValue.ToString())
            {

                item.Quantity = item.Quantity + result;

                MessageBox.Show(cbStockQnt.SelectedValue.ToString());
            }
     }



 }
}
```

}

If you can read this spaghetti junk, I'm stuck at getting the quantity of the selected piece of clothing to change. How do I get it to change the value both in the list and in the combobox?

Comment: Just to say that the MessageBox.Show is only there so I can see if anything actually happens to the values.

Comment: Use a BindingList rather than a List